# Загрузка файла js, node js

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, npm

Сделана веб-страница, собирается модульно. Использую node js, сервер node-static.

Мне нужно реализовать загрузку файла, то есть с компа и потом на устройство чтоб по кнопке файлик загрузился.

Пока пробую с компа на свой же комп, по нужному мне пути, но не получается никак. Уже перепробовал всякие модули npm.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Промежуточный обработчик:
middleware.js

```
import multer from 'multer';
import path from 'path';
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (request, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, 'uploads/');
  },
  filename: (request: Request, file: any, cb: any) => {
    cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  }
});

export const upload = multer({ storage });
```

Подключение к роутеру:
router.js

```
import { Router } from 'express';
const router = Router();
import { upload } from './middleware'; 
router.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), (req, res, next) => {
  // ваша логика
}
export default router;
```

Разметка html:
index.html

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="image" />
</form>
```

Если babel не используется, замените import на require и export default на module.exports